# Tomcat from 8443 to 443

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, tomcat7, tomcat8

I have spring MVC web application started on tomcat  8.

I'have created certificates for SSL Authorization.
I have such I confing in a server.xml

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" 
  keystoreFile="ks.p12" 
  keystoreType="pkcs12" 
  keystorePass="*****"
  port="8443"
  scheme="https"
  secure="true" 
  sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Ok. Now Everything works well!

BUT how to start server on 443 port?
When I try to use open https://dev-sp.ge/  it gets me that messages "This webpage is not available"

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In unix systems the use of ports under 1024 usually requires special permissions or rights.

Your Tomcat works with port `8443` because it is not in the "protected" port range.

Of course first step is to change the port to `443` in your Tomcat's `server.xml`.

#### Solving using Authbind

One way to allow Tomcat to use 443 or 80 ports is to use [Authbind](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/authbind.1.html)

> **authbind**  allows  a program which does not or should not run as root to bind to low-numbered ports in a controlled way.

Lower than 1024 ports have to be enabled in: `/etc/default/tomcat8`. Add the following line:

```
AUTHBIND=true
```

And create a new file for this:

```
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/443
sudo chown tomcat8 /etc/authbind/byport/443
sudo chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/443
```

#### Solving using setcap

Another way to solve this is to allow an executable binary to bind to the restricted ports which can be enabled by using the `setcap` unix command:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /path/to/binary
```

Comment: What if we are configuring the project in docker container ?

Comment: For those still having problems accessing Tomcat externally at port 80 or port 443 even with authbind configured, for me it turned out the virtual Ubuntu I was using runs the UFW firewall, and extra commands such as "sudo ufw allow 443/tcp" (and/or 80/tcp) were necessary.

Answer (score 9):

Solution that worked for me: redirect 443 requests to 8443.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

Use (`/sbin/`)`iptables-save` (as root) to make changes permanent.

Answer (score 1):

PREROUTING was not working for me.
I successfully achived that with:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to 8443
```

sudo /sbin/iptables-save  (to make it permanent)

Answer (score 0):

Requires MacOSX >= Yosemite.

Add:

```
echo "
rdr pass inet proto tcp from my-domain.com to my-domain.com port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 9443
" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

Or:

```
echo "
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 9443
" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

List:

```
sudo pfctl -s nat
```

Remove:

```
sudo pfctl -F all -f /etc/pf.conf
```

https://salferrarello.com/mac-pfctl-port-forwarding/

Answer (score 0):

Like to add something more to @icza 's answer (since I'm new I cannot post comments)

If you are running the Tomcat server inside Eclipse, use

```
authbind --deep ./eclipse
```

Because Eclipse does not care about the authbind otherwise